# Congrats for buying a new thing

Tags: phrases

Let's say a girl bought a pair of new beautiful shoes.

What usually would say friend or anyone who sees/informed about this new purchase?

I mean something similar with "Congratulations for buying a new house" or similar.

How teenagers would congrats their friend with a new purchase?

Thanks.

Comment: For shoes, it can be something like: "Nice shoes!", "Cool shoes!", "Where d'you get those shoes?" but less often **congratulations**, for things which require more **struggle** and **effort** to obtain, one might say: "Congratulations on the new house / baby / job !"

Comment: @Peter I'm a teenager and I'd say the same thing.

Comment: This depends on culture. Who do you you want to say this to? A teenager in/from the US? The UK? Saudi Arabia? Japan?

Comment: "Struggle" is relative. An online friend of mine in India worked everyday for four months to buy a Windows XP laptop with 2GB RAM. This was in 2015. I congratulated him because it took serious effort. In America, the laptop is a paper weight. To him, it was an accomplishment.

Comment: @JimReynolds How is it different?

Comment: @Pot I don't know exactly, but I think it can be important. I live in Taiwan, for example. A Taiwanese student can say to a Taiwanese English teacher, *Here is my homework. Please correct it.* That is polite. If someone said it to an American English teacher, it is likely to sound rude. In some cultures it may be appropriate to "congratulate" someone for buying shoes. In another culture, like in the US, Peter's answer above is conventional. Sometimes we need to consider who we are talking to if we want to send a certain message. That's all I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"**Well done  / Great job** for buying such nice new shoes"

"**Well done  / Great job** on finding those beautiful shoes / on finding a great bargain".

Answer (score 2):

Just say something pleasant to confirm you noticed the new item.

> They suit you. You look beautiful! Nice shoes! Cool!

It's not the case you make some progress though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I look for some universal way to say that: I mean like "Congratulations!"

Comment: Just say " Great! Cool!" It's universal.